# How to parse a String in fact of Drools (Double comparison)

Tags: string, parsing, double, drools

When one inserts a new object in drl file and afterward wants to compare its String representation of a number with another number in next rules Drools gives an exception. It is much clearer with an example.

```
rule "rule_1"
dialect "mvel"
salience -10

when

then
    Resource resource = new Resource();
    resource.setAmount("10"); //note - this accepts only Strings
    insert(resource);
end

rule "rule_2"
dialect "mvel"
salience -20

when
    $resource: Resource(Double.parseDouble(amount) > 0.0) //exception
    //$resource: Resource(amount == "10") - no error here
then
    System.out.println("$resource.value = " + $resource.amount);
end
```

Exception is: Caused by: [Error: Double.parseDouble(amount): null]
[Near : {... Double.parseDouble(amount) > 0 ....}]
--------------^
Interesting is that when you compare it as a String (amount == "10") - it works fine. But when you try to parse "amount" to Double then Java doesn't know that there is any value at all (thinks amount == null and therefore cannot parse it).
The second interesting thing is that if you created this object (resource) in java and inserted it before "fireAllRules()" - "amount" field become visible to the parser and it works.
But the matter is that I cannot create this object before firing rules because I don't know wheter there will be a need of it. And my fields must be String as well. And I have to compare it like "more than" or "less than", so comparing strings doesn't apply. 
I tried to create a function before the rule like:

```
function boolean isValid(String s){
    try {
        Double.valueOf(s);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Doesn't work also.

Comment: As you said, the reason of the exception is because when the expression `Double.parseDouble(amount)` is evaluated, the value of `amount` is null. The reason why it works with the String comparison is because in the expression `amount == "10` Drools understands that `amount` is null so it evaluates the expression as false.
With the rules as you show them, you shouldn't get any exception. Are you sure you don't have any other `Resource` inserted into your session? Are you sure you don't have any extra logic in the getter/setter of `amount`? Could you reproduce this in a small project?

Comment: I've made this project for demonstration so there are only these two rules. But anyway let me come to my lap and share via GitHub. And about amount == 10...it is not only goes without exception, but also comes as true and firing rule so that the string appears in console. Resourse has only one field with gretter and setter

Comment: Haha! When I created separate project it worked! Sorry, I was wrong. 
Yes, the problem is that I had another resources with amount == null field. Then how should I compare not being caught by an exception of null pointer? Because I have a lot of resources and I cannot give them 'amount = "0"'

Comment: Now I see one way so far: Resource(amount != null, Double.parseDouble(amount) > 0)

Comment: ^ that is correct

Answer (score 1):

So here the problem was that I had another object that matched a given fact but with amount = null. And then Drools tried to parse it to double that, of course, led to exception. So the way to solve it is checking the amount:

```
Resource(amount != null, Double.parseDouble(amount) > 0)
```